# How to access the MERN app Node server (localhost) on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, mern

I have a MERN stack application and I'm trying to do the API page to provide data for external applications. I have a server that runs a GET request and my MERN application should check a token and provide correct data. I assume I need somehow to trigger a node server because react can't provide the data I need. On the localhost, it's easy to do. I just run GET `http://localhost:5000/data/api` on Postman and get the data I need. But how to access localhost on the remote server? My MERN application is hosted on Heroku and by triggering a `https://example.com/data/api` I'm getting the react app. How can I do the GET API call from the Postman to the Heroku server and get the data?
Thanks!

Comment: You need do deploy your localhost application somewhere publicly accessible

Comment: @qkhanhpro yes, I deployed MERN application no Heroku. Do you mean, I need to deploy nodejs part one more time separately?